# Is it risky to use the Google credential provider for windows? what happen if the GCPW stop working in the future

Tags: g-suite, google

We have the following:-

1. G-Suite Basic edition.
2. 55 Windows 10 PCs.
3. We install the Google credential provider for windows inside the Windows 10 machines.
4. and we associate Google accounts with existing Windows profiles
5. so now users are login to their PCs using their google accounts.

everything seems working well.. but i am afraid of the following scenario:-

let say Microsoft publish some windows updates in the future and one of these updates cause the GCPW to stop working for a reason or another.. so in this case all our users will not be able to login to their PCs.. is my concern valid? if it is valid then how i can overcome this issue?

Comment: In that scenario, couldn't users just use their old existing Windows accounts to log in?  That being said, it is a risk - it's my policy to try to avoid running under the feet of tech giants who could decide to go to war at some point, but it's not always avoidable.

Comment: @HiredMind since we associated the windows profiles with google accounts, so their windows profiles will get replaced by the google accounts...